# How to sum varchar column in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am a beginner in SQL. I need to sum up the gender column.I mean how many males and how many females are there in a Table.This is what i tried.

```
SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN Gender='Female' THEN Gender ELSE 'Null' END)Gender,
SUM(CASE WHEN Gender='Male' THEN Gender ELSE 'Null' END)Gender
FROM EmployeeDetails;
```

I am getting this error:
Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Operand data type nvarchar is invalid for sum operator.

So i tried the following query:

```
Select length(Gender) - length(replace(Gender, ' ', '')) + 1 NumbofWords
```

from EmployeeDetails

Its showing as length is not a recognized builtin function.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little bit of an XY solution, given that it produces rows and not columns. But this is more "database-y", and essentially what you have is a `PIVOT`ed version of the following anyway.

You can't *add* words, but you can *count* them. So just `GROUP BY` your `Gender` column and `COUNT`:

```
select Gender, count(*)
from EmployeeDetails
group by Gender
```

Comment: This is quite easy to sum the word. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

`SUM + CASE` will work, but you need to sum numbers like:

```
SELECT
   SUM(CASE WHEN Gender='Female' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [FemaleNumber],
   SUM(CASE WHEN Gender='Male' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [MaleNumber]
FROM EmployeeDetails;
```

SQL Server 2012+

```
SELECT
  SUM(IIF(Gender='Female', 1, 0)) AS [FemaleNumber],
  SUM(IIF(Gender='Male', 1, 0)) AS [MaleNumber]
FROM EmployeeDetails;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... Its working. Thanks once again for your immediate response.